# Google maps API not working with PhoneGap - generating blank page

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps, phonegap-build

I am using the Adobe phonegap build site and trying to create a very basic single page html to utilize the Google Maps API, unfortunately which is not working. It is only generating a blank white page.

My index html...

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html style="height:100%">
  <head>
  <script src="lib/maps.js"></script>//I have copied the Google maps JS locally
  </script>

  <script>
      function initialize() {
           alert("Initialize called...");
           var mapProp = {
           center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
           zoom:5,
           mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       };
       alert("Map props loaded...");
       var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
       alert("The div innerHTML"+document.getElementById("googleMap").innerHTML);
     }
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
 </head>

 <body style="height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0">
   <div id="googleMap" style="height:200px;position:relative;"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

My phonegap config.xml...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <widget xmlns       = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id          = "org.aninda.areyouclose"
    versionCode = "10"
    version     = "1.1.0">

<name>Test App</name>

<description>
    Test
</description>

<author href="http://www.aninda-bhattacharyya.com" email="aninda@gmail.com">
    Aninda Bhattacharyya
</author>

<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/contacts"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>

<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="android" density="ldpi" />
<icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="android" density="mdpi" />
<icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="android" density="hdpi" />
<icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="android" density="xhdpi" />

<access origin="googleapis.com" subdomains="true"/>

</widget>
```

I am banging my head for more than 8 hours now. Please help!

Comment: Have you tried a PhoneGap emulator?  It would probably be easier to retreive any error messages using that.  Not sure if that plays well with the Adobe site.

Comment: That is my next target and thanks for the pointer @Seano666. Trying to find out first with experts if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: You are assigning height in all places, but never width? Could that be the issue?

Comment: Dawson, I can definitely give it a shot. So do you suggest adding a width of 100% to both html and body, some px to the div?

Comment: You have to listen to the cordova deviceready event, after that you can start your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought of answering my own question after figuring out what was the issue. Missed to include the cordova whitelist plugin in the `config.xml`. Addded the following line and voila...

```
<gap:plugin name="com.indigoway.cordova.whitelist.whitelistplugin" version="1.1.1" />
```